# If `when (a) in x..y` is deprecated, what should I use instead?

Tags: kotlin, deprecated

So im trying to do a when statement for when a is in a certain degree of 360, this is the method I'm currently using:

```
var a: Double = 0.0

...

primaryDirection = when (a) {
    in 45..135 -> Direction.RIGHT
    in 135..225 -> Direction.DOWN
    in 225..315 -> Direction.LEFT
    else -> Direction.UP
}
```

However each of the `in` keywords is saying that it's deprecated... So what should I replace this with?

Comment: What is telling you about the deprecation?  I'm in IntelliJ, and it's quite happy with your code.  I admit, I haven't done much with Kotlin yet, so it could be user error in terms of not having a recent language version set or something like that.

Comment: @Steve probably cuz i didnt word the question well enough - the error was caused by `a` being a double and the range being ints

Comment: Glad you figured it out, and also glad my tools aren't misbehavin'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I just figured it out... Its because 'a' was a Double and the range was an Int range, changing a to be an int fixed the warning.

[image: Image of the warning explains it better]

Comment: But the message was saying something about deprecation.  What, is that mismatch going to outright fail in later Kotlin versions?

Comment: @Steve I added  a pic of the warning

Comment: cool.  It's helpful to see that full explanation.  Thanks.